# Misleading UI when trying to raise multiple flags

Tags: bug, flags, user-interface

I recently flagged a low-quality answer (full text of answer: "Your answer is may be best. Thank u.") with a "Not An Answer" flag. Upon further investigation I grew suspicious that there may have been some sock puppet action going on (the answer was immediately upvoted and accepted, and OP and answerer had the same username). As a result I clicked the flag button again on the answer and was met with essentially following dialog (mine didn't have the "very low quality" flag because the answer had been upvoted):

[image]

To me, this dialog suggests that I am allowed to raise any additional flag other than "not an answer" because all the other options can be selected as usual in the dialog. After typing the minimum number of characters in the custom flag box, the "Flag Answer" button became blue, just like usual.

After crafting my well-written custom flag text explaining the situation and clicking the "Flag Answer" button, I was dismayed to get the following message:

[image]

I have no problem with the rule that you can't double flag an answer (and it didn't slow me down in this case -- I just custom flagged the question instead of the answer, and the mods swiftly handled the situation), but I do think the flag dialog should be modified to indicate that no additional flags can be raised. Not only does it make more sense as a user interface, but it will prevent custom flag messages from getting gobbled up into an angry red box.

Comment: Oh, and if you really want mods to act on something, you can flag something else and explain, or poke them in chat. But you probably already know this.

Comment: Until I got to the end of this, I was expecting you to be talking about the "you have already raised this type of flag" message being placed next to the bold heading of the next flag type :)