# Either allow flagging an answer twice for different reasons, or fix the interface accordingly

Tags: bug, flags

This is a bug.

What I did:

1. I flagged an answer and chose "not an answer" as the reason for flagging
2. Then I attempted to flag it again, this time choosing "In need of moderator intervention" in order to add more detail

At step 2, I was presented this interface:

[image]

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOR**

**Either**:

A. Given the interface above, I should be allowed to choose any of the non-disabled options, including the last one, and flag the answer one more time.

**or**

B. If you cannot flag the same answer twice, even for different reasons, then the interface shown above should be changed accordingly: **ALL** of the options should be greyed out, especially the textarea, **or not displayed at all** and the warning should be made clearer to state that you **cannot** flag the question again, for any reason (not only the one you already flagged it for)

---

**OBSERVED BEHAVIOR**

I was allowed and encouraged to **waste my time** filling in the textarea with details about the reason I was flagging the answer, and **only when I submitted the form** I got an error message telling me that I could not report the answer because I already had.

Comment: Super annoying UI! I posted about it [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295941/misleading-ui-when-trying-to-raise-multiple-flags), but sadly didn't hear back.

Comment: I understand the UI issue, but why do you see the need to flag it 2 different times? Why not just flag it *in need of moderator intervention* and add info about why it's not an answer and a mod needs to get involved?

Comment: @DaveZych the example I ran into in the dupe was flagging as NAA, then noticing that there was some sock puppet action, and then trying to flag with a long custom flag describing all my evidence of sock puppetry. Unfortunately my carefully crafted custom flag was lost because my NAA flag was still not resolved and you can't have two concurrent flags. The UI shouldn't let you type hundreds of characters if it's not going to accept it.